# Восстановление бекапа 2008 сервера на 2005.

Tags: sql-server

Возникла необходимость переноста бекапа на 2005 Sql сервер . Пробовал просто сгенерировать скрипт, который запросос переносит сами данные , но возникает проблема : база большая , сам скрипт весит около 500 Мб и Management Studio даже не хватает памяти чтобы загрзуить этот скрипт. Пробовал даже на куски пилить его , но все равно все очень сильно тормозит. Еще пробовал через программу red gate([http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)) .Но там что-то никак не могу толком понять как один бекап (2008) привести к другому (2005) . Может кто работал с этой утилитой ? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще как то размыто звучит ваш вопрос.
В каком виде бекапы?
То что нельзя развернуть это понятно версии файлов разные, с 2008 базу не приаттачишь к 2005.
Так же в 2008 есть новые фичи, которые не будут работать в 2005, а некоторые будут работать не правильно.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx

Можно с помощью самого SQL SERVER вытянуть, то что нужно и как вам нужно. 
Но это конечно не самый короткий путь.

Comment: Проясню размытость своего вопроса : есть бекап базы (файл .bak) сделанный в 2008-м сервере . Нужно восстановить этот бекап на 2005-ом сервере, вот и все в принципе. Вопрос : как это сделать, исключая способ непосредственного формирования скрипта с структурой и данными (insert скрипты с данными + описание самой структуры на).

Comment: Возможно кто-то работал с программой red-gate (SQL Data Compare) . Она как раз для этого предназначена , я просто не могу понять как там один бекап приводить к другому.